# How to grant Firebase Specific or Firebase Admin role to a user in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: firebase, roles, amazon-iam, firebase-console

On adding Manager Users in Firebase console, I am redirected to Google IAM Page. There is no role specifying Firebase or anything related to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Help: Manage Project Members](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000272?hl=en)

Every Firebase project is backed by a Google Cloud project. That's why you get sent to the IAM page.

You can set the new member's role to any of the [primitive roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions) (viewer, editor, or owner).

Comment: Fine, but Primitive Roles are kind of deprecated. How about the more granular roles - any documentation about which one is required for a given Firebase feature?